# Change connection on saving-event

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to change the connection on the saving event. Here is what I have done so far:

I make and event on the `saving` method:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($model)
    {
        $model->connection = 'test';
        var_dump($model);
        return $model;
    });
}
```

And then I make a save on `User`.

```
$user = new User();
$user->save();
```

When that is done, it still uses the default `connection` instead of the `test`-connection I have set.

I have both a `default` and a `test` connection configured in `app/config/database.php` which you can see below: (OBS: The change is the `prefix`)

```
// ...
'connections' => array(

    'default' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'test' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'test_',
    ),

),
// ...
```

The `var_dump` turns out with the following, where you can see that the `$model->connection` have been changed.

```
object(User)[159]
  ...
  protected 'connection' => string 'default' (length=7)
  ...
```

But for some reasons it stills goes into the table `users` instead of `test_users`.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: 1. Your database config has `default` and `draft` not `default` and `test`, but I'm guessing that that's just a forgot-to-edit thing. As for the situation at hand - `$connection` is a protected variable on the `Model` class, so it's unlikely that you can edit it by using `$model->connection = 'xyz';` but you might find calling `$model->setConnection('xyz');` will more correctly do what you want. Or maybe I'm way off.

Comment: @alexrussell, you were right about the configuration, thanks for pointing it out. But using the `$model->setConnection('xyz');` changes it as well in the `var_dump` but not in the actual SQL.

Comment: Short answer: you can't do that. You can't swap connection on the already built `Query\Builder`, which is the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this by overriding Eloquent's `save`-method.

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    // set draft connection
    Config::set('database.default', 'test');

    // do the actual save
    parent::save($options);

    // change back to original connection
    Config::set('database.default', 'default');
}
```